# Scikit learn (Python 3.5): Do I need to import a library to make this work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am working through [Python Data Science Essentials (2nd Edition)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Python-Data-Science-Essentials-Second-ebook/dp/B01MAYMIZ3).

The book provides the code below:

```
chosen_random_state = 1
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, ran-dom_state=chosen_random_state)
print ("(X train shape %s, X test shape %s, \ny train shape %s, y test shape %s" \
% (X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape))
h1.fit(X_train,y_train)
print (h1.score(X_test,y_test))
```

When I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-137-c5136df13468> in <module>()
          1 chosen_random_state = 1
    ----> 2 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=chosen_random_state)
          3 print ("(X train shape %s, X test shape %s, \ny train shape %s, y test shape %s" % (X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape))
          4 h1.fit(X_train,y_train)
          5 print (h1.score(X_test,y_test))
    
    NameError: name 'cross_validation' is not defined
```

I suspect that I might have to import a library which the book is not mentioning. I have searched the manuals but cannot find this function. IS this a function I need to create or can someone point me to the relevant library?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`cross_validation` submodule of `sklearn` is [deprecated](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cross_validation.py#L39). You should use `sklearn.model_selection` [instead](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html)

```
from sklearn import model_selection

...
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=chosen_random_state)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is this deprecated in Python 3.6? It doesnt throw a warning when I call it now in Python 3.5

Comment: Not in `Python 3.6`. But when you move to newer version of scikit (0.20), you will get an error on import of `cross_validation` submodule.

Comment: Thanks!! really concerned with this book now. It is a "new " edition that keeps giving me wrong / out of date methods

Comment: Its because sklearn will be upgraded faster than a book can be written and published. That happens all the times. BTW, is not related to python upgrade, but the library itself

Answer (score 0):

You must import this:

```
from sklearn.svm.libsvm import cross_validation
```

Comment: Thanks for answering really quick. When I do as you say, I get another error. Updating answer now

Comment: The other answer provided seemed to work. Really curious why that worked and tours didnt. Is it because drilling down to libsvm by passes the files containing the train_split_test method?

Answer (score 0):

You should import

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
```

Make sure u have installed sklearn. See [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html) for instruction on how to Install

Comment: Thanks!!! for some reason @marcin swiercyzyna's method threw another error but this worked!. Using anaconda so must of these came pre instaled\

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your issue. try it

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, ran-dom_state=chosen_random_state)

print ("(X train shape %s, X test shape %s, \ny train shape %s, y test shape %s" \
        % (X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape))

h1.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, ran-dom_state=chosen_random_state)
print ("(X train shape %s, X test shape %s, \ny train shape %s, y test shape %s" \
% (X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape))
h1.fit(X_train,y_train)   
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, ran-dom_state=chosen_random_state)
    print ("(X train shape %s, X test shape %s, \ny train shape %s, y test shape %s" \
    % (X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape))
    h1.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.